# hook_block_view not being called

Tags: 7, blocks, hooks

I have a custom module which has some custom blocks in. My blocks display in the block page so they are being registered with `hook_block_info`.

However my modules are not displaying anything on the screen. I have added a `dpm('hit')` at the the top of `hook_block_view` for my module but nothing is being displayed.

I have added `hook_block_view_alter` to my module and see that the blocks are being displayed there but with the `$data` parameter being null/empty.

I have run my code through the coder module and it is not seeing any errors.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you show your code? Difficult to debug without that. BTW The coder module won't tell you if your code's correct, just whether on not it conforms to Drupal's code standards

Answer (score 2):

After looking around the code I ended up the `_block_load_blocks` function. Before calling `drupal_alter('block_list', $block_info);` I had 6 elements in `$block_info`. After the function had run I had 2 items.

Doing some digging in `drupal_alter` I fount out what modules were touching `$block_info`. The domain module was removing the blocks.

Looking at the settings on the block page I did not have my domain ticked. The message under the domain options did say:

> Limit block display to these affiliates. This block is visible on all
>   domains by default using this theme.

So thought the block would appear by default. This was not the case.

Comment: Thanks for bring up this response. Keep contributing to the Drupal.SE community.